# how to call stored procedure with multiple tables in hibernate hbm file and pojo and also java class

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping

```
SELECT emp.employeeId, emp.employeeFirstName, comp.companyname, dept.departmentname 
FROM Employeetable emp, Companytable comp, departmenttable dept 
WHERE emp.employeeCompanyId=comp.companyId AND emp.EmployeeDepartmentID=dept.DepartmentID;
```

The employeetable hbm file:

```xml
<sql-query name="callrealtimeprocedure">
    <return alias="employeetable" class="com.AdiSys.eRMS.entity.Employeetable"/>
    <return-join alias="companytable" property="com.AdiSys.eRMS.entity.Employeetable"/>
    <return-join alias="companytable" property="com.AdiSys.eRMS.entity.Employeetable"/>
</sql-query>
```

The employeetable pojo:

```java
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "callrealtimeprocedure",
query = "CALL realtime(:employeeId,:employeeFirstName)",
resultClass = Employeetable.class
)
})
@Entity
```

Similarly department hbm and pojo.

My java class after creating session:

```java
Query EmplyeeQuery = session.createSQLQuery("CALL realtime(:employeeId,:employeeFirstName,:companyname,:departmentname)")
        .addEntity(Employeetable.class)
        .addEntity(Companytable.class)
        .addEntity(Departmenttable.class)
        .setParameter("employeeId", "")
        .setParameter("employeeFirstName","")
        .setParameter("companyname", "")
        .setParameter("departmentname", "");
```

I'm not able to find out how to link up stored procedure sql query in hbm and pojo and java class

Comment: What do you mean link up?  Do you mean that the stored procedure returns a result set, which you want to convert to a collection of POJOs?  Please clarify.  And please make an effort to format your code better.

Comment: hi david sorry for not posting question properly.my question is - i have three tables companytable,employeetable and departmenttable.i have created stored procedure containing sql query -SELECT emp.employeeId,emp.employeeFirstName,comp.companyname,dept.departmentname FROM Employeetable emp,Companytable comp,departmenttable dept where emp.employeeCompanyId=comp.companyId and emp.EmployeeDepartmentID=dept.DepartmentID; What i want is how do we map this hbm files and pojo and java class.if you provide a link with an example it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a start, I wouldn't have bothered with the stored procedure.  The whole point of using Hibernate is that you don't need to write any SQL.  If you're going to write SQL, then there's not much to be gained by using Hibernate.

A really good source of Hibernate documentation is http://www.hibernate.org/docs - if you go to the "Core Reference Manual" for whichever version of Hibernate you have, you'll find some really good examples on how to set up your POJOs.

Also, I don't know if you're planning to use Hibernate annotations.  I like these - they're a lot less messy than using separate XML files.  Have a look at the "Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide" (from the same link, under v3.5) for guidance on using them.

Comment: thanks for your advice david.one more doubt is there,is there any other way other than annotations which you recommend for mapping stored procedures

Comment: Annotations are an optional extra; you don't need to use them at all.  But why are you so interested in stored procedures?  They don't really fit well with Hibernate, since the whole point of Hibernate is to avoid writing SQL.

Comment: i agree with your advice,the reason why i'm desperate in using stored procedure is performance issue where in its taking long time for real time records and to show existing records from database querying nearly 15 queries checking many tables which hibernate is causing.even after adjusting batch update size in configuration.xml.any suggestions

Comment: How long is a "long time"?  What DBMS are you using?  Is this the actual query that's performing poorly, or is it just an example?  If it's the actual query, then how many rows are there in the employee table?  Replacing naked queries with stored procedures is unlikely to fix a serious performance problem; but there are loads of other techniques for tuning database performance.  In general though, this really doesn't have anything to do with Hibernate or Java.

Comment: i'm using mysql.its was an example.could you tel me techniques to tune database performance.

Comment: @Mahendra - whole books have been written about this, so I can't really do justice to the subject in a comment here.  Perhaps you could ask a specific question about tuning performance, and I'll do my best to answer.  However, I have very little experience of mySQL, and a lot of tuning techniques are quite DBMS-specific.  Alternatively, you can post an ACTUAL query that's performing poorly, I might be able to give you some specific things to check (like indexes that you might need, or statistics to gather, etc)