# MySQL: Call stored procedure (returning data from multiple tables) from hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, primefaces

I've a stored procedure in mysql which receives multiple parameters.
Now, i want to call it from hibernate in java.
Also, I want to implement lazy loading, so that if for example there are 50,000 records in the db. The procedure does not return all the records at once but only when the user need it.
I'm using primefaces datatable to show the data.

**Note** I do not all the columns of the database tables, i need only 5 to 6 db columns on the basis of the parameters which the user will provide to the stored procedure. For this purpose, i've created POJO whose list will hold the date.

**Summary**

1. Call stored procedure from hibernate and pass multiple arguments to
   it.
2. Implement lazy loading to increase the efficiency of the
   application.

**UPDATE** OK, I used CallableStatement and ResultSet which solved my problem 1 in the above mentioned summary

Any suggestions about 2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call stored procedure with multiple tables in hibernate hbm file and pojo and also java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224824/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-multiple-tables-in-hibernate-hbm-file-and-pojo)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it's a possible duplicate. But if you take a look at my question in its entirety you'll find that I in the Summary i also mentioned lazy loading as my second point. BTW, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's usually no need to fetch more than a handful of fields for tens of thousands of rows at once. Majority of the use cases fall into a category of fetching just a few columns from a large number of rows or fetching a large number of columns for only a handful of rows. In good ol' pre-ORM days the standard approach was to create two queries, one returning a result set/cursor with a few columns and another one - returning all columns for a single row. Also, two value objects were created for handling the results of these stored procedures. Looks like you are about half way there, so you as well can implement this approach in its entirety using Hibernate.